# Grabing Information from Yahoo finnance jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

So i have started with some java, i am not that good i am still a beginner..

what im trying to do is grab specific information from Yahoo finance with Jsoup.

```
public class WebScraping {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=AAPL&annual";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        String information = document.select(".yfnc_tabledata1").text();
        System.out.println("Information: " + information);


    }
}
```

but i get the whole table i want specific information like the Net Income and the income only for year 2015

Comment: Which HTML elements do contain the information you are interested in? The CSS class `yfnc_tabledata1` probably is to broad.

Comment: i want the Net Income From Continuing Ops for the year 2016 that is 45,687,000

Answer (score 0):

so i found the solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=AAPL&annual";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    String information = document.select("table tr:eq(7) > td:eq(2)").text();
    System.out.println("Information: " + information);


    }
}
```